# shell script with arguments presented

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#if present -a flag then print this echo
#echo "A";
#if -b is present then print b
#echo "B"

#and if -c 10 present how can I read this value '10'  ?
```

above is how I want to look my script

and I want to be able to start it like this

```
myscript.sh -a -b -c 10
```

or

```
myscript.sh
```

or

```
myscript.sh -a -c 10
```

or

```
myscript.sh -c 10
```

and so on

Answer (score 3):

Type 'man getopt' at your shell, and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Use getopts like this:

```
arg=-1
while getopts "c:ab" optionName; do
   case "$optionName" in
   a) echo "-a is present";;
   b) echo "-b is present";;
   c) arg="$OPTARG"; echo "-c is present [$arg]";;
   esac
done
```

Comment: started with only -b ("myscript.sh -b") gives this  "./myscript.sh: option requires an argument -- b
OPT: ?
"

Comment: Sorry I had one typo, pls check updated script now. Options without argument should come in the end after colon `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at getopts .

The following example is taken from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
```

http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_automate/_Passing_to_shell_script.html